# Run second screen process after first screen process complete?

Tags: process, gnu-screen

Is it possible to start a screen process, but let it wait for another running screen process to complete? Basically creating two screen processes like so:

```
screen -S myfirstprocess
screen -S mysecondprocess
```

And then start `myfirstprocess` and tell `mysecondprocess` to start after `myfirstprocess` has completeted.

If this does exist, is it possible to make one process depend on the completion of multiple other processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you simply want this:

```
screen <COMMAND> ; screen <COMMAND1>
```

Try with other commands, this for example:

```
sleep 3; echo hi
```

will first sleep for 3 seconds and after that it will print `hi`. You can read more on that in `Lists` chapter in `man bash`.

Comment: Essentially the ; is the same as &&. But what I am trying to do is to define the process dependencies, because I furthermore want to make for instance two processes dependent on one process. With ; and && I can't do that.

Comment: No, `&&` is not the same as `;` - when `&&` is used the second command will run only if the first one succeeded but when `;` is used the second command will always run.

Comment: And if you want 2 processes to run *in parallel* after a previous process has finished that's also possible with `;` and `&` - is that what you want?

Comment: Ok, that's quite a difference between ; and &&. Thanks!

Comment: Well, whether they run in parallel or not isn't important here. The only thing important is being able to tell that B and C can only run after A has completed. Or in another scenario C can only run after A and B have both completed.

Comment: Isn't the first one equivalent to `sleep 3; echo a; echo b`? Both `echo a` and `echo b` will be ran after `sleep 3` finishes.

Comment: And the second one will work `;` too - `a; b; c` - `c` will run after `a` and `b`.

Comment: Ok, I still though have no depencency between the processes. The problem comes with the following example. D is dependent on A, B and C. E is only dependent on A and C, but not on B. What I need is to be able to define dependencies like known from graphs or Gantt diagrams or BPMN process diagrams.

Comment: Solves my case though more or less. Thanks @ArkadiuszDrabczyk